# Github Actions: poetry installs black but CI workflow does not find it

Tags: python, continuous-integration, github-actions, python-poetry

I am setting up a python code quality workflow locally (pre-commit) and on Github Actions (GHA). Environment is managed with poetry.

While the local precommit works fine, the remote GHA workflow fails, saying it does not find black, while looking at the workflow logs it seems it was installed just fine. Workflow was largely copied from this great writeup: https://jacobian.org/til/github-actions-poetry/

Where am I making a mistake? Here are the relevant files:

**codequal.yml**

```
name: Python QA

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  pylint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Python QA

    steps:
    - name: Check out
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: "3.10"

    # Cache the installation of Poetry itself, e.g. the next step. This prevents the workflow
    # from installing Poetry every time, which can be slow. Note the use of the Poetry version
    # number in the cache key, and the "-0" suffix: this allows you to invalidate the cache
    # manually if/when you want to upgrade Poetry, or if something goes wrong. This could be
    # mildly cleaner by using an environment variable, but I don't really care.
    - name: cache poetry install
      uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: ~/.local
        key: poetry-1.3.2

    # Install Poetry. You could do this manually, or there are several actions that do this.
    # `snok/install-poetry` seems to be minimal yet complete, and really just calls out to
    # Poetry's default install script, which feels correct. I pin the Poetry version here
    # because Poetry does occasionally change APIs between versions and I don't want my
    # actions to break if it does.
    #
    # The key configuration value here is `virtualenvs-in-project: true`: this creates the
    # venv as a `.venv` in your testing directory, which allows the next step to easily
    # cache it.
    - uses: snok/install-poetry@v1.3.3
      with:
        version: 1.3.2
        virtualenvs-create: true
        virtualenvs-in-project: true
        installer-parallel: true

    # Cache your dependencies (i.e. all the stuff in your `pyproject.toml`). Note the cache
    # key: if you're using multiple Python versions, or multiple OSes, you'd need to include
    # them in the cache key. I'm not, so it can be simple and just depend on the poetry.lock.
    - name: cache deps
      id: cache-deps
      uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: .venv
        key: pydeps-${{ hashFiles('**/poetry.lock') }}

    # Install dependencies. `--no-root` means "install all dependencies but not the project
    # itself", which is what you want to avoid caching _your_ code. The `if` statement
    # ensures this only runs on a cache miss.
    - run: poetry install --no-interaction --no-root
      if: steps.cache-deps.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'

    # Now install _your_ project. This isn't necessary for many types of projects -- particularly
    # things like Django apps don't need this. But it's a good idea since it fully-exercises the
    # pyproject.toml and makes that if you add things like console-scripts at some point that
    # they'll be installed and working.
    - run: poetry install --no-interaction

   ################################################################
   # Now finally run your code quality tools
   ################################################################

    - name: Format with black
      run: |
        black 'src'

    - name: Lint with pylint
      run: |
        pylint --fail-under=7.0 --recursive=y --enable=W 'src'
```

**Relevant section of GitHub Action logging of codequal.yml**

```
Run poetry install --no-interaction --no-root
Creating virtualenv rssita in /home/runner/work/rssita/rssita/.venv
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 49 installs, 1 update, 0 removals

  • Updating setuptools (65.6.3 -> 67.0.0)
  • Installing attrs (22.2.0)
  • Installing certifi (2022.12.7)
  • Installing charset-normalizer (3.0.1)
  • Installing distlib (0.3.6)
  • Installing exceptiongroup (1.1.0)
  • Installing filelock (3.9.0)
  • Installing idna (3.4)
  • Installing iniconfig (2.0.0)
  • Installing nvidia-cublas-cu11 (11.10.3.66)
  • Installing nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11 (11.7.99)
  • Installing nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11 (11.7.99)
  • Installing nvidia-cudnn-cu11 (8.5.0.96)
  • Installing packaging (23.0)
  • Installing platformdirs (2.6.2)
  • Installing pluggy (1.0.0)
  • Installing tomli (2.0.1)
  • Installing typing-extensions (4.4.0)
  • Installing urllib3 (1.26.14)
  • Installing cfgv (3.3.1)
  • Installing click (8.1.3)
  • Installing coverage (7.1.0)
  • Installing identify (2.5.17)
  • Installing emoji (2.2.0)
  • Installing mccabe (0.7.0)
  • Installing mypy-extensions (0.4.3)
  • Installing nodeenv (1.7.0)
  • Installing numpy (1.24.1)
  • Installing pathspec (0.11.0)
  • Installing protobuf (4.21.12)
  • Installing pycodestyle (2.10.0)
  • Installing pyflakes (3.0.1)
  • Installing pytest (7.2.1)
  • Installing pyyaml (6.0)
  • Installing requests (2.28.2)
  • Installing sgmllib3k (1.0.0)
  • Installing six (1.16.0)
  • Installing torch (1.13.1)
  • Installing tqdm (4.64.1)
  • Installing types-urllib3 (1.26.25.4)
  • Installing virtualenv (20.17.1)
  • Installing black (22.12.0)
  • Installing feedparser (6.0.10)
  • Installing flake8 (6.0.0)
  • Installing isort (5.12.0)
  • Installing mypy (0.991)
  • Installing pre-commit (3.0.2)
  • Installing pytest-cov (4.0.0)
  • Installing stanza (1.4.2)
  • Installing types-requests (2.28.11.8)
1s
Run poetry install --no-interaction
  
Installing dependencies from lock file

No dependencies to install or update

Installing the current project: rssita (0.1.0)
0s
Run black 'src'
/home/runner/work/_temp/0fc25aa8-4903-45ae-9d8e-9c11f60dca11.sh: line 1: black: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

**Project tree on local:**
(base) bob@Roberts-Mac-mini rssita % tree

```
.
├── README.md
├── __pycache__
│   └── test_feeds.cpython-310-pytest-7.2.1.pyc
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.cfg
├── src
│   └── rssita
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   ├── __init__.cpython-310-pytest-7.2.1.pyc
│       │   ├── __init__.cpython-310.pyc
│       │   ├── feeds.cpython-310-pytest-7.2.1.pyc
│       │   ├── feeds.cpython-310.pyc
│       │   ├── rssita.cpython-310-pytest-7.2.1.pyc
│       │   └── termcolors.cpython-310-pytest-7.2.1.pyc
│       ├── feeds.py
│       ├── rssita.py
│       └── termcolors.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-310.pyc
    │   └── test_feeds.cpython-310-pytest-7.2.1.pyc
    └── test_feeds.py
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the dependencies are installed in a virtual environment managed by Poetry, you need to use Poetry to [`run`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#run) Black:

```yaml
- name: Format with black
  run: poetry run black ./src
```

Comment: OMG this is both embarassing and extremely useful :) Thanks so much!!! While we're at it, other than pylint, black and mypy, are there other useful "code quality" processes I could investigate? (code coverage I do under the testing workflow)

Comment: [Flake8](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/) with its numerous [plugins](https://github.com/DmytroLitvinov/awesome-flake8-extensions).

Comment: Also, as you are already using *pre-commit*, you could use it to run all linting/formatting checks using a [marketplace action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/pre-commit) because in your *.pre-commit-config.yaml* you could have Flake8, Black, as well as other checks like [interrogate](https://github.com/econchick/interrogate). Samples: [.pre-commit-config.yaml](https://github.com/ts-mk/flake8-bas/blob/master/.pre-commit-config.yaml), [workflow job](https://github.com/ts-mk/flake8-bas/blob/ccb7c10f78f6e88b5af3a71cc62fd7be235c53cd/.github/workflows/tests.yml#L25)

Comment: yes I am using pre-commit and in it use flake8. now must understand if keeping the pre-commit and the github actions somewhat aligned is feasible. would be great! Thanks a lot (maybe that's achievable with the pre-commit marketplace action you linked above?)

Comment: Is is feasible and "aligned" because both locally and in GitHub Actions they would use the same configuration. When pre-commit is installed as a Git hook, you could view its invocation as **pro-active** - don't commit something that doesn't pass the checks. The invocation in GitHub Actions is then seen as a **safety check** - spot issues that were not even supposed to be committed but were because a developer skipped the checks before commit.

Comment: May the force be with you! :) Thanks

Comment: To expand on what I said, there are actually (at least) 3 ways to run pre-commit, **all with the same single config**: 1. Manually using `pre-commit run --all-files`. 2. As a Git hook after doing `pre-commit install`. 3. As a job in GitHub Actions or other CI tool.

Comment: So far I had routiney used #1 from my venv shell, and also having configured the hooks get the same (hopefully) actions on a commit to GitHub. Thanks to your advice might add it to my GA CI. In that case wonder if I might just scrap my current "linting" workflow in favor of this pre-commit approach. Thanks again!!!